# What is best approach to update the user info in custom component user-info table?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, user, administrator, joomla-1.5

I have developed a custom component that store some user information in separate tables, I want to store/update user information when user deleted or updated from admin section or front end.

Comment: In regards to code, show us how you currently are doing it.

Comment: Its basic functionality to update the custom component table when user database updated .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should save your data using a User Plugin - they're *very* easy to write.  An example can be found at [Creating a profile plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin), though the example might have more than you need.

The events your code would go into are `onUserAfterSave` and `onUserAfterDelete` and are documented at [Plugin/Events/User](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User).  These events will fire when a user is saved or deleted in the admin or Front-end.

The guts of the plugin would be this:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
class PlgUserMyPlugin extends JPlugin
{
    protected $app;
    protected $db;

    public function onUserAfterDelete($user, $success, $msg) {
        if (!$success) 
            return false;

        $query = $this->db->getQuery(true)
        ->delete($this->db->quoteName('#__mytable'))
        ->where($this->db->quoteName('userid') . ' = ' . (int) $user['id']);
        $this->db->setQuery($query)->execute();
        return true;
    }

    public function onUserAfterSave($user, $isnew, $success, $msg) {
        if (!$success) 
            return false;

        // Update your table here
        if ($isnew) {
            // New User
        }else{
            // Existing User
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @GDP, I think this is the best way to achieve the required functionality without modifying core files.